# Can you add a DTD schema to an biztalk created XML if you don't have the DTD?

Tags: xml, xslt, biztalk

We need to create an XML for a SHipping software company that we deal with.

Basically, the output xml needs to contain the below doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE INTERFACE_CREATE_SHIPMENT SYSTEM "INTERFACE_CREATE_SHIPMENT.dtd">
```

but i don't have this file, so adding it to the mappings Doctype system causes an error so i don't know if it would work. Is it possible to let BizTalk add this doctype without the DTD being avaible on my side? or could i make a new DTD with the same name just to be able to create the file?

Comment: The best solution would be to get the DTD from the company, but I guess this is not possible?

Comment: @cvesters I am trying to obtain the DTD file. But i can't be sure if they will be giving it us or not.

Comment: Do you just need the `!DOCTYPE` declaration, or do you also need to use elements/attributes/etc. defined in that DTD (that you won't be defining in your XSD for BizTalk)?

Comment: @DanField We only need the !DOCTYPE to be part of our output. We received the rules for the XML in a word file and are following that. Now the other side just says the file fails because it needs that DOCTYPE filled in. Getting the actual DTD would be preferable but deadlines might not allow us to wait for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to set your own custom xml declaration at design time in your pipeline component

In the "Add processing instructions text" field you should put

```
  <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?><!DOCTYPE INTERFACE_CREATE_SHIPMENT SYSTEM "INTERFACE_CREATE_SHIPMENT.dtd">
```

Don't forget to set the Add XML Declaration to false

[image]

More details are available here http://cherifmahieddine.com/2013/09/23/custom-biztalk-xml-declaration/

Comment: This does not look right. The OP wants to add a DOCTYPE declaration, not an XML declaration or a processing instruction.

Comment: He wants to add this Doctype declaration in his output XML, with this solution you can add whatever you want, i mean you can set your xml declaration + adding a doctype without any validation(hence without validation error). THIS IS THE SOLUTION WITHOUT ANY CUSTOM DEVELOPPEMENT

Comment: OK, if you say so. Suggesting to use the "Add processing instructions text" field for something that is clearly not a processing instruction just seems confusing to me.

Comment: An XML File starts with xml/xsl processing instruction followed (optionally) by a doctype declaration i agree that doctype has nothing to do here but the way MS implemented this is that you can put there all xml/xsl processing instructions + doctype declaration, so yes the term used is not exactly correct but :)

Comment: This works after i changed the weird quotes. Your quotes on version and standalone are invalid for XML on my end (this might be localisation?) Anyway, changing them all to the same type of quotes as you copied from my example makes it all work.

Comment: Its just a typo error (copy paste from my blog), i'm glad it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just need the `!DOCTYPE` declaration, and you can't get the actual .dtd file, you'd have two options:

1. Mock up the .dtd file.  Not really preferable, as this could cause problems with conflicting definitions, and later developers are likely to misunderstand that it's just a mock file.
2. Create a pipeline component to add the `!DOCTYPE` declaration in the Encode stage.  This should work as long as you don't need anything special from that dtd.